# Convert plain text file to Hadoop sequence file in Spark

Tags: java, xml, hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce

My existing project is using Hadoop map-reduce to generate a sequence file having a custom key and value which is in XML format.

The XML value is generated by reading one line at a time from the input source and the RecordReader is implemented to return the next value in XML format from the plain text.

e.g. Input source file has 3 rows (1st row is the header and rest rows is having actual data)

```
id|name|value
1|Vijay|1000
2|Gaurav|2000
3|Ashok|3000
```

Post the map method the sequence file has data as below:

```
FeedInstanceKey{feedInstanceId=1000, entity=bars}   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><bars><id>1</id><name>Vijay</name><value>1000</value></bars>
FeedInstanceKey{feedInstanceId=1000, entity=bars}   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><bars><id>2</id><name>Gaurav</name><value>2000</value></bars>
FeedInstanceKey{feedInstanceId=1000, entity=bars}   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><bars><id>3</id><name>Ashok</name><value>3000</value></bars>
```

Question: I wish to implement the same in Spark. Basically, read the input file and generate the key value pair as above.

Is there any way/possible to reuse the existing InputFormat and hence the RecordReader which is used in my Hadoop mapper class.

The RecordReader is responsible/having the logic to convert the plain text row to XML and return as value to Hadoop map method for writing in `context.write()` method.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in the Spark documentation in the [External Datasets](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#external-datasets) section. The important part for you is:

> For other Hadoop InputFormats, you can use the
>   JavaSparkContext.hadoopRDD method, which takes an arbitrary JobConf
>   and input format class, key class and value class. Set these the same
>   way you would for a Hadoop job with your input source. You can also
>   use JavaSparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD for InputFormats based on the
>   “new” MapReduce API (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce).

Here's a simple example demostrating how to use it:

```
public final class ExampleSpark {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JavaSparkContext spark = new JavaSparkContext();
        Configuration jobConf = new Configuration();

        JavaPairRDD<LongWritable, Text> inputRDD = spark.newAPIHadoopFile(args[0], TextInputFormat.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class, jobConf);
        System.out.println(inputRDD.count());

        spark.stop();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

You can see the Javadocs for JavaSparkContext [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html#newAPIHadoopFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)).